# Android Studio - Duplicate class

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors, duplicates

I'm working on an old project that I need to update.

I can't compile because I have this error that I can't solve:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver found in modules jetified-firebase-iid-17.0.3-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.0.3) and jetified-firebase-messaging-23.2.1-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.2.1)
     Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.ExperimentalPathApi found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathRelativizer found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathReadWriteKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathUtilsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.jdk7.AutoCloseableKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.jvm.jdk8.JvmRepeatableKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.jvm.optionals.OptionalsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.random.jdk8.PlatformThreadLocalRandom found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$1 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$2 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$3 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$4 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.text.jdk8.RegexExtensionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.time.jdk8.DurationConversionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
```

This is my build.gradle :

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlinVersion = "1.8.0"
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.8'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
android {
    signingConfigs {
        release {
        }
    }
    compileSdk 33
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "fr.xxx.yyy"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 42
        versionName '1.0.42'
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            assets.srcDirs = ['/src/main/res/raw']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            //useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            zipAlignEnabled true
            // useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            // signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.10.1'
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.appolica:interactive-info-window:v1.0.6'
    implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:6.1.16'
    implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:21.4.1'
    // Recommended: Add the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics.
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.3.0'
    // Add the Firebase Crashlytics SDK.
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.4.0'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:blurry:4.0.1'
    implementation 'com.baoyz.swipemenulistview:library:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:32.1.2-jre'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I understand that I have a duplicate class problem, but I can't seem to solve it.

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Thx for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
> Duplicate class com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver found in modules jetified-firebase-iid-17.0.3-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.0.3) and jetified-firebase-messaging-23.2.1-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.2.1

The first duplication says Firebase, so I would look into updating your Firebase dependencies, you have at least 7 :-) and if two have versions then clash then you can run into a problem.

Look at the firebase bom: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/learn-more#bom

> Even though each Firebase library is versioned independently, they are
> built together to ensure that the latest release of each library is
> compatible with the others.
>
> By using the BoM to manage your app's Firebase library versions, you
> don't need to track which version of a Firebase library is compatible
> with another Firebase library.

```
dependencies {
  // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
  implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.2.2')
```

This will let you use firebase versions for all your dependencies that are compatible.

This might not fully resolve your duplication problem, but it'll remove one possible cause.

---

It also says the duplication is because of jetifier:

jetified-firebase-messaging-23.2.1-runtime
and
com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.2.1

That would be this tool: https://developer.android.com/tools/jetifier

> The standalone Jetifier tool migrates support-library-dependent libraries to instead rely on the equivalent AndroidX packages. The tool lets you migrate an individual library directly instead of using the Android Gradle plugin bundled with Android Studio.

> Jetifier migrates Java, XML, POM, and ProGuard references that point to android.support.* packages, changing them so they point to the corresponding androidx.* packages.

It does this by repackaging in a new jar (iirc).

You should check if any of your dependencies are (very old) using support library versions - and update those first, this'll stop jetifier kicking in for that dependency & potentially remove the duplication.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your reply ! 
I've added firebase-bom to my dependencies but I don't think it's made a difference :/
I've updated all my dependencies via "Files>Project Structure>Dependencies" but I still have this duplicate class problem.
"Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver found in modules jetified-firebase-iid-17.0.3-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.0.3) and jetified-firebase-messaging-23.2.1-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.2.1)"
How can I use just one version of the class ?

Comment: Are you aware you don't just add the bom dependency, you then remove the versions from all your others? (docs explain it better than I do)

Comment: Yes. 1/ I added the bom dependency. 2/ I removed all versions from "com.google.firebase:firebase-*" 3/ it didn't work, so I added the version on 3 firebases (core/crash/invites). 4/ I think the firebase duplicate classes are solved. 5/ I think I have a problem with Jetifier now, which duplicates 2 firebase classes (?) - The first line "Duplicate Class" in my first post :/

Comment: #3 is a step in the right direction though, so keep it. The jetifier removes the support library dependency from your 3rd party dependency, "most" recent dependencies no longer use support library - so I think if you bump all your versions up it means the jetifier is less involved and you may end up being able to remove it. https://adambennett.dev/2020/08/disabling-jetifier/